# How Do I Use a Windows 10 Disc Image in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-image

**What I would like advice with:**
I have A PC that had previously dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.  I have instead decided to use my Linux install as my main system and run Windows virtually from it on the same device.

**What I have done:**
To start with I simply used Ubuntu to create disk images of my Windows partitions with the intent to restore them as a virtual machine. Ubuntu saved each of them in its preferred .img format.  Now that I have installed VirtualBox the options are to either to burn the disk images back to a physical drive and use the .vmdk format to boot virtually that way or convert the .img format to .dvi and spin up a wholly virtual disk. The latter conversion is a built-in feature of VirtualBox that I have tested and seems to work. `VBoxManage convertdd efi.img EFI.vdi`

**What I should know going forward:**
Something that does not get mentioned in any of the Q&As I have read is the fact Windows 10 comes with four partitions (the main system "C:drive", the reserved partition, the recovery partition, and the efi boot partition).  I created a separate disk image for each one of these for thoroughness but I don't know if this is necessary or if the C:drive is all that is required for the VM.  How would one even load multiple .dvi images at once? notwithstanding the fact that the efi bootloader was already configured to dual-boot Ubuntu, (so having two bootloaders = 2×hairpulling)

**Stumbling through weeds:**
Just this clarification is all I need in the near-term to save time, however, any further advice is welcome since this will likely prove an arduous task later on, like considering whether it is okay to keep the .dvi on the same partition as my Linux install or whether or not Windows will still activate.

Comment: What's your question? That's a nice stream of thoughts but I am not sure what answers you need.

Comment: Specifically, my most important question at the moment is, do I require all four Windows partitions to properly create the VM, and secondly, if so, how do I get VirtualBox to run these multiple .dvi or .vmdk disk images as a complete system?  I ask these questions because while I had to create a separate disk image for each partition, the fact that Windows uses multiple disc partitions is oddly left out of any and all of the discussions I have read on this subject.

Comment: I've no idea why you want to split partitions into separate vmdk images. The rest three are very small. Windows does not need a recovery partition per se. It absolutely needs System EFI partition, Reserved Partition and a partition with Windows itself. That's it. It's a question for superuser.com - not unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, I don't think you understand, they are ALREADY separate (img.) disk image files.  I could not just create a single disk image of the whole SSD containing all partitions, especially since it included my Linux install actively doing the imaging.  What I might need to do is the opposite: combine separate .vmdk or .dvi images into one (after conversion from .img of course) if this is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the virtual box commmands I've used on Ubuntu 22.04 with VirtualBox version 17.0 to install the evaluation copy of Windows 10 Enterprise.

You need to get that first. You can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-10-enterprise).

https://gist.github.com/angstyloop/80cea18f767562351ab5f9917cf3f1ec

```
#!/bin/sh

# create-windows-enterprise-vm-from-iso.sh

# Use VBoxManage to create a VirtualBox VM from an evaluation copy of Windows 10
# Enterprise ISO. 

# Follow the download instructions for your region at
#
# https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-10-enterprise
#

# Create a virtual machine named "windows-10-enterprise-bob" from and ISO

name=windows-10-enterprise-bob

vboxmanage createvm --name $name --ostype Windows10_64 --register --basefolder `pwd`

# Turn on IO APIC
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --ioapic on

# Designate RAM size and video RAM size
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --memory 4096 --vram 128

# Create an internal network interface connected to the internal network named
# RedTeamLab
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --nic1 intnet --intnet1 RedTeamLab

# Put the network interface in promiscuous mode
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --nicpromisc1 allow-all

vboxmanage createhd --filename `pwd`/$name/$name_DISK.vdi --size 60000 --format VDI
vboxmanage storagectl $name --name 'SATA Controller' --add sata --controller IntelAhci 
vboxmanage storageattach $name --storagectl 'SATA Controller' --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium `pwd`/$name/$name_DISK.vdi
vboxmanage storagectl $name --name 'IDE Controller' --add ide --controller PIIX4
vboxmanage storageattach $name --storagectl 'IDE Controller' --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium `pwd`/windows-10-enterprise.iso
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --boot1 dvd --boot2 disk --boot3 none --boot4 none

#vboxmanage startvm $name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay, thanks! I've updated my post with a description, instead of just a link and a block of code!